# aspx email photo submission

Tags: asp.net

I am new to asp.net, I am trying to have a photo contest on my website.

I want users to upload their pictures on my site and I want to get an email with the picture attachment to my email ID.

How can I do this and is there a better way of doing this(I have to use asp for this)

Thanks,
jack

Answer (score 0):

It should be relatively simple by using the [FileUpload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.aspx) webcontrol on the aspx form and using [System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx) to send a [MailMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.aspx) with an [attachment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.attachments.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Well if you wanna do it in vb you would do something like this :

```
Dim message As New Mail.MailMessage
Using message

   message.To.Add(New Mail.MailAddress("notyou@gmail.com", "Name Reciever"))

   message.From = New Mail.MailAddress("you@gmail.com", "Name Sender")
   message.Subject = "subject!"
   message.Body = "Text!"

   message.Attachments.Add(New Mail.Attachment("pic.jpg"))

   Using smtp As New Net.Mail.SmtpClient("Your smtp")
                        smtp.Send(message)
End Using
```

But you prob use c# but you din't say so ... but it prob looks alike anyhow  ^^